# I am getting the following error: "ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 3, 1)" but I am passing a 2-d input. What is happening here?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, valueerror

My entire code is below. However, read my whole post since much of it works well enough.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

trade_date_lim = "5/1/2021"


chrome_driver = os.path.abspath('C:/Users/ross/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)


#path is workbook I want to read from, eventually write to
path = r"C:\Users\ross\Desktop\reit.xlsx"
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet = workbook["Tickers"]
max_rows = sheet.max_row
ticker_array = []

for row in range(2, max_rows + 1):
    ticker = sheet.cell(row=row, column=1)
    ticker_array.append(ticker.value)


wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
symbol_array = []

for stock in ticker_array:
    browser.get('https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Default.jsp')

    #using clicks and send_keys, gets the bond page for a desired stock
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                           '#TabContainer > div > div.rtq-tab-wrap > div.rtq-tab-menus-wrap > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a > span'))).click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#firscreener-cusip'))).send_keys(stock)

    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.qs-no-info")))
    except TimeoutException:
        pass

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                           "#ms-finra-advanced-search-form > div.ms-finra-advanced-search-btn > input:nth-child(2)"))).click()
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-agreement > input"))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        pass

    #clicks to sort by earliest date, clicks again to sort by latest maturity
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-grid-hd > div > div:nth-child(7) > div"))).click()
    time.sleep(5)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-grid-hd > div > div:nth-child(7) > div"))).click()
    time.sleep(5)
    #gathers all bond offerings on first page
    whole_chart = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-scrollpanel > div.rtq-grid-scroll"))).text

    #gets number of bonds listed on page so we can iterate through them. Some pages have differing number of bonds listed. Most on page is 20
    parent = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ms-finra-search-results"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div')
    count_divs = len(parent.find_elements_by_xpath("./div"))

    bnd_off_cnt = 1
    row_num = 0

    while row_num < count_divs and bnd_off_cnt < 3:

        #gets values that I'm looking for
        symbol = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-scrollpanel > div.rtq-grid-scroll > div > div:nth-child(" + str(row_num + 1) + ") > div:nth-child(3)"))).text
        maturity = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-scrollpanel > div.rtq-grid-scroll > div > div:nth-child(" + str(row_num + 1) + ") > div:nth-child(7)"))).text
        moody_rating = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-scrollpanel > div.rtq-grid-scroll > div > div:nth-child(" + str(row_num + 1) + ") > div:nth-child(8)"))).text
        sandp_rating = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-scrollpanel > div.rtq-grid-scroll > div > div:nth-child(" + str(row_num + 1) + ") > div:nth-child(9)"))).text
        stated_bond_yield = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-scrollpanel > div.rtq-grid-scroll > div > div:nth-child(" + str(row_num + 1) + ") > div:nth-child(11)"))).text

        #looks to see if all values are non-empty and if moody rating and sandp rating are not equal to 'WR' and 'NR'
        if symbol.strip() and maturity.strip() and moody_rating.strip() and sandp_rating.strip() and stated_bond_yield.strip() and moody_rating != "WR" and sandp_rating != "NR":
            #bond detail page below
            element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-finra-search-results > div > div.qs-resultData > div.qs-resultData-body > div.rtq-grid.rtq-grid-auto-h > div.rtq-scrollpanel > div.rtq-grid-scroll > div > div:nth-child(" + str(row_num + 1) + ") > div:nth-child(2) > div > a")))
            element_link = element.get_attribute('href') #gets the link

            #opens window, switches to it and opens the bond detail page
            browser.execute_script("window.open('');")
            time.sleep(3)
            browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
            browser.get(element_link)

            #switch to iframe on second page and clicks it
            wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "ms-bond-detail-iframe")))
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#tradeHistory_link"))).click()
            #switches to third page
            browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
            #sleeps for 3 seconds so we know for sure that we are working on right page
            time.sleep(3)


            # get length of table on trades page and iterate through them trying to find the most recent "Trade" status
            bond_trades = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-glossary > div > table > tbody > tr")))
            count = len(bond_trades)


            for trade in range(count):

                bond_trade_status = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-glossary > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + str(trade + 1) + ") > td:nth-child(4) > div"))).text
                if bond_trade_status == "Trade":
                    bond_last_traded = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-glossary > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + str(trade + 1) + ") > td:nth-child(1) > div"))).text
                    if bond_last_traded > trade_date_lim:
                        #prior bond yields occasionally don't match the yield that it was last traded at
                        bond_yield = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ms-glossary > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + str(trade + 1) + ") > td:nth-child(7) > div"))).text
                        symbol_array.append(symbol)
                        bnd_off_cnt += 1
                        break
                    else:
                        continue
                    #test for if we are within X amount of time from today
                    #continue if we are more than that amount of time
                    #exit if we are within time frame and get 'Yield'
                else:
                    continue
            browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[2])
            browser.close()
            browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
            browser.close()
            browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])
        row_num += 1


np_symbol_arr = np.array(symbol_array)

np_symbol_arr.resize((3,1))
print(np_symbol_arr.shape)
print(np_symbol_arr)


df = pd.DataFrame([np_symbol_arr])

path = r"C:\Users\ross\Desktop\reit.xlsx"
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine="openpyxl")
writer.book = book

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Healthcare")
writer.save()
```

I am getting an error on this line near the very bottom of my code: `df = pd.DataFrame([np_symbol_arr])`. The lines previous I print out the shape of the numpy array and the values in the numpy array. The shape is (3, 1) and the values are as follows:

```
[['NHI5113928']
 ['MPW5083277']
 ['MPW4860582']]
```

So it looks like I am passing a 2-d array (or so I think). What is going on here? Why does it think I'm passing a 1, 3, 1 array?

Error type: ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 3, 1)

Any and all help appreciated!

Ross

Comment: `np_symbol_arr.resize((3,1))` does not operate in-place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it because you have embedded your array inside another Python list.  That becomes the 1st dimension.  Change your call to

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np_symbol_arr)
```

without the extra brackets.